# Change audio volume when headphones are plugged in KDE

Tags: debian, audio, kde, audio-volume

I am working on Debian 7 with KDE Version 4.8.4. I want the volume to be reduced automatically when I plug my headphones, I know it is not a problem with my computer (at least directly) because it used to work that way when I had Kubuntu.